# Inkscape Extensions: How to get installation path?

Tags: python, inkscape

In the inkscape [wiki page for Effect Extensions](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/PythonEffectTutorial) it is recommended to include this at the beginning of the script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/share/inkscape/extensions') # or another path, as necessary
```

This is needed to be able to import the `inkex` class, which is needed to develop the extension.

However, I don't think it is good practice to have such a hard-coded string with the installation directory.

So, the question is: Is there a way to get the inkscape extensions directory programmatically, in a way that is portable and adapts to each user's installation of inkscape?

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) say that the `module.__file__` attribute is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded, if it was loaded from a file, so you could probably use that (after `import`ing `inkscape`) as the root of the `extensions` subdirectory. You can use `os.isdir()` to make sure it exists.